# How to avoid repeating strings?

Tags: python

My code is:

```
import random
WORDS = ('python', 'football', 'facebook', 'photo') #list of words that will be riddled
word = random.choice(WORDS)
correct = word
jumble = ''
hint = 'hint'
score = 0
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position] 
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):] #creating jumble of correct words
print('Welcome to the game "Anagrams"')
print('Here`s your anagram:', jumble) #Welcoming and giving a jumble to a player
guess = input('\nTry to guess the original word: ')
if guess == correct:
    score += 5
    print('You won! Congratulations!') #end of game in case of right answer
if guess == hint: #situation if player asks a hint
    if correct == WORDS[0]:
        print('snake')
    elif correct == WORDS[1]:
        print('sport game')
    elif correct == WORDS[2]:
        print('social network')
    elif correct == WORDS[3]:
        print('picture of something')
    score += 1
while guess != correct and guess != '': #situation if player is not correct
    print('Sorry, you`re wrong :(')
    guess = input('Try to guess the original word: ')
print('Thank you for participating in game.')
print('Your score is', score)
input('\nPress Enter to end')
```

When asking hint string :

> 'Sorry, you`re wrong :('

repeats.
It looks like:

> Try to guess the original word: hint
>   sport game
>   Sorry, you`re wrong :(

How to make this string appear only in case of wrong guess?

Comment: `while guess != correct and guess != '' and guess:`
    `print('Sorry, you`re wrong :(')` doing exactly what you want to do

Comment: I tried to place there `and guess != hint`
but in case of this program ends when asking of hint

Comment: The indentation seems wrong to me. Is it only a part of your game?

Comment: They are similar to indentations in my editor and they are not wrong. It`s full version

Comment: @AntonL. then your game is probably lacking of another loop. Am I right: you want to guess more than one random word? But that was not your question. I have difficulties to get your idea.

Comment: @Wolf, no. I want to ask only one word, but when player asks hint he gets it, but he also gets string "Sorry, you`re wrong :("
I want this string appearing only in case of wrong answer, not in case of asking hint

Comment: the issue tracked, but u wanna achieve? what after `hint`?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque, only the string with hint, not the string which tells to player that he is wrong

Comment: Listen, this line is printing because after the if clause                                         `if guess == hint:` your code jumps to the `while` loop, and as the guess is wrong, the line is printing.

Comment: @AntonL. Yes I saw this meanwhile. Please have a look at my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, when the player types `hint` the player gets a hint, but then the program tests the `'hint'` string against the `correct` word. Of course, `'hint'` isn't the correct answer, so your program tells them that it's wrong.

Just for fun, I've optimized your code a little, and improved the scoring logic. :)

Your letter-jumbling `for` loop is quite clever, but there's a more efficient way to do this, using the `random.shuffle` function. This function shuffles a list, in place. So we need to convert the chosen word into a list, shuffle it, and then join the list back into a string.

I've also replaced your hints logic. Rather than having to do a whole bunch of `if` tests to see which hint goes with the current word it's much simpler just to store each word and its associated hint as a tuple.

```
import random

#Words that will be riddled, and their hints
all_words = (
    ('python', 'snake'),
    ('football', 'sport game'),
    ('facebook', 'social network'),
    ('photo', 'picture of something'),
)

#Randomly choose a word
word, hint = random.choice(all_words)

#Jumble up the letters of word
jumble = list(word)
random.shuffle(jumble)
jumble = ''.join(jumble)    

print('Welcome to the game "Anagrams"\n')
print('You may ask for a hint by typing hint at the prompt')
print('Wrong guesses cost 2 points, hints cost 1 point\n')

print("Here's your anagram:", jumble)

score = 0
while True:
    guess = input('\nTry to guess the original word: ')
    if guess == word:
        score += 5
        print('You won! Congratulations!')
        break

    if guess == 'hint':
        #Deduct a point for asking for a hint
        score -= 1
        print(hint)
        continue

    #Deduct 2 points for a wrong word
    score -= 2
    print('Sorry, you`re wrong :(')

print('Thank you for participating in game.')
print('Your score is', score)
input('\nPress Enter to end')
```

Comment: we are coming back to the original question about (not) repeating strings ;-)

Comment: @Wolf: Yes, when I read this question's title I was expecting a somewhat [different issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) . :)

Comment: Yeah, that's is the purpose of structure :-)

Answer (score 3):

change you last while to this:

```
while guess != correct and guess != '':
    guess = input("Sorry, you`re wrong:( ")
```

Comment: Anton wants that in case of a wrong answer only this appears: Sorry, you`re wrong :(.

Comment: @LetzerWille I fixed the indentation, hope it helps! And I think your answer helps solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try to fix some problems:

this

```
if guess == hint: #situation if player asks a hint
```

should probably be

```
elif guess == hint: #situation if player asks a hint
```

And also this seems wrong to me

```
while guess != correct and guess != '': #situation if player is not correct
    print('Sorry, you`re wrong :(')
    guess = input('Try to guess the original word: ')
```

should be probably changed into that (indentation is important):

```
    guess = input('Try to guess the original word: ')
if guess != correct and guess != '': #situation if player is not correct
    print('Sorry, you`re wrong :(')
```

I have not tried this corrections in a complete program.

Comment: i am not downvoting, but consider this situation, if user guess correct word after the hint?Will never print the congratulation phrases.

Comment: It solves the problem, but creates new: player has only ony try to answer.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I only tried to point on the most suspect parts. After all, this program seems to be only a first sketch or proof of concept. BTW: i found the game idea nice (afer reading carefully ot understand the indentation).

Comment: @AntonL. Well, we are fare from answering "How to avoid repeating strings?"

Comment: @Wolf, i mean no harm. I am just telling even your code will create some problem, as one of them is stated above. Though it's not your problem. The code of OP has some fundamental logical issue.

Comment: @Wold I corrected your code a bit. I replaced tihs `print('Sorry, you are wrong :(')` with this `guess = input('Sorry, you are wrong :(. Try one more time: ')` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your special logic for a correct guess and for the special input `"hint"` is only run once on the very first guess. Your loop for incorrect values always runs after that. I think you want to move all the logic into the loop:

```
while True:  # loop forever until a break statement is reached
    guess = input('\nTry to guess the original word: ')
    if guess == correct:
        score += 5
        print('You won! Congratulations!')
        break # stop looping
    if guess == hint: # special case, asking for a hint
        if correct == WORDS[0]:
            print('snake')
        elif correct == WORDS[1]:
            print('sport game')
        elif correct == WORDS[2]:
            print('social network')
        elif correct == WORDS[3]:
            print('picture of something')
        score += 1
    else: #situation if player is not correct, and not askng for a hint
        print('Sorry, you`re wrong :(')
```

I've left out the situation where your code would exit the loop on an empty input. If you want that, you should add it explicitly as an extra case, with a `break` statement.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque did you have a **closer look** at [LetzterWille's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32669333/2932052)?

Comment: The problem with this answer is the score logic: if you chose to get the hint instead of just guessing you get 6 points instead of 5.

Comment: @Wolf: It's worse than that, you can keep asking for a hint over and over to get more and more points. I didn't make up the logic, though it's what was already there. Probably subtracting a point would make more sense.

Comment: @Blckknght Well, the loops: some are missing, some are surplus ;-) I missed a big loop when looking on the question the first time and then I tried to accept that it's a one-way game. Programming remains exciting...